# Center only the middle <li>

Tags: html, css, html-lists

My fiddle so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/dzjqor2d/

I just can't get the middle `<li>` to center, whatever I try.

My Code:

```css
ul {
  width: 60%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #F5FAFF;
  padding: 20px;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #388CD1;
  color: #F5FAFF;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
ul li:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    Empty cart
  </li>
  <li>
    Continue shopping
  </li>
  <li>
    Update cart
  </li>
</ul>
```

Note:

Content is dynamic, so is the width of the container

Comment: add your css here

Comment: You want justify list?

Comment: If you can use flex-box - check this link - https://jsfiddle.net/3kyLk4rr/

Comment: Might want to drop your comment as answer :) @San

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make first `li` to left and last to right rest will `float` as per `ul`'s text-alignment:

```
ul {
  width: 60%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #F5FAFF;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #388CD1;
  color: #F5FAFF;
  position:relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

ul li:last-child{
  float:right;
}
ul li:first-child{
  float: left;
}
```

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dzjqor2d/9/)**

Comment: Yes, that's even a better answer than the flexbox. The flexbox messes with the rest of the cart (using magento 1.9). Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to float the last **li** right, use margins to get the alignments right:

```
ul li {
margin: 0 20px;
list-style: none;
float: left;
padding: 10px 20px;
background-color: #388CD1;
color: #F5FAFF;
position:relative;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

- https://jsfiddle.net/dzjqor2d/8/

Comment: But what if the content is dynamic?

Comment: You'll want something a bit more robust depending on min/max length of content and # of list items! The float solution above is fine for just the 3 li's, but I'd use a grid framework if it gets any more dynamic (getskeleton is my current favourite for this)

Comment: True, although, the question was only for 3 items. If there where more, I would have used another approach.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the CSS3 `:nth-child()` Selector with your `ul` and `li` tag

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Empty cart
  </li>
  <li>
    Continue shopping
  </li>
  <li>
    Update cart
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  width: 60%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: #F5FAFF;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align:center;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #388CD1;
  color: #F5FAFF;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
ul li:nth-child(1){
  float:left;
} 
ul li:nth-child(3){
  float:Right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These days [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) is the way to go, in the past floating was great, but now not so much.

for the `UL` I've added `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;` this means; make them all fit in one block and if there is extra space, just put have space between them.

Here have a look:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  background-color: #F5FAFF;
  padding: 20px;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #388CD1;
  color: #F5FAFF;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    Empty cart
  </li>
  <li>
    Continue shopping
  </li>
  <li>
    Update cart
  </li>
</ul>
```

I've changed the width to make the example easier to see.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Just use below css for ul:

ul {width: 70%;overflow: auto;background-color: #F5FAFF;padding:20px;display: flex;}

Comment: That's far from what I'm asking :/